# How to get the average of relation table? laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there an eloquent way to get the average from relation table? Here I have 2 tables.

I can get the average of all exams using `withAvg`, but I want also to get the average of each exam (see expected result). Can someone give an idea how to do it? thanks

Models:

```
Student (students)
- id
- name

Exam (exams)
- id
- title
- is_correct
- student_id

StudentExam (studentExams)
- id
- section
```

---

I have tried this one and its working fine.

```
StudentExam::whereSection(1)
 ->with('exams')
 ->withAvg('exams AS total_avg_exams', 'is_correct);
 ->first();
```

This results into:

```
{
    section: 1,
    total_avg_exams: 0.63,
    exams: [{},{}],
}
```

**expected result** would be:

```
{
    section: 1,
    total_avg_exams: 0.63,
    exams: [
        {
            avg_exams: 0.83,
            ...
        },
        {
            avg_exams: 0.63,
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the exams in the with statement. I will asume al the exams that are related share the same title so it should be something like this.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

StudentExam::whereSection(1)
 ->with(['exams' => function($query){
//You need the title for grouping
//You will need the student id for the eager loading so relation works
//is_correct is needed for the query
return $query->select(
 'title', 
 'student_id', 
 'is_correct', 
 DB::raw('avg(is_correct) as total_avg_exams'))
->groupBy('title');
}])
 ->withAvg('exams AS total_avg_exams', 'is_correct');
 ->first();
```